# How to fix printer unable to process requests and falling in queue?

Tags: linux, printer

I am running on Oracle Linux 5.1. The jobs that are submitted for printing by the application are falling into the print queue but not getting cleared. How to troubleshoot this scenario?

```
$ lpstat -t
printer MATERIALSJD3 now printing MATERIALSJD3-7.  enabled since Mon 13 Nov 2017 03:26:37 PM MYT
MATERIALSJD3-1          appltest         10240   Mon 13 Nov 2017 03:26:37 PM MYT
MATERIALSJD3-2          appltest         10240   Mon 13 Nov 2017 03:29:35 PM MYT
MATERIALSJD3-3          appltest         10240   Tue 14 Nov 2017 08:52:15 AM MYT
MATERIALSJD3-4          appltest         10240   Wed 15 Nov 2017 12:50:46 PM MYT
MATERIALSJD3-5          appltest          7168   Thu 16 Nov 2017 03:09:38 PM MYT
MATERIALSJD3-6          appltest         10240   Fri 17 Nov 2017 09:09:11 AM MYT
MATERIALSJD3-7          appltest          7168   Fri 17 Nov 2017 03:47:19 PM MYT
```

Comment: Are these all printers?

Comment: MATERIALSJD3 is the printer. MATERIALSJD3-1 to 7 are requests waiting in queue.

Comment: If it's one printer it  could be the driver, it could be the way the printer is configured.